# How start second for loop at + 1 every iteration?

Tags: python

I have two for loops like

```
jj = 0

for ii in range(filename_list.__len__()):
    jj += 1
    for jj in range(filename_list.__len__()):
        if ii != jj:
            print(str(ii) + " " + str(jj) + "\n")

    print("=" * 5)
```

every time the `ii` for loop fully executes I want the next `jj` for loop to execute starting at the index +1 of what it was before.

currently, the output looks like

```
0 1
0 2
=====
1 0
1 2
=====
2 0
2 1
=====
```

but it should look more like

```
0 1
0 2
=====
1 2
```

thus for every iteration of the `ii` for loop there should be one less iteration for the `jj` loop.

Comment: In that case if I understand the question correctly, you need to have your loops nested differently. ```for jj in range``` needs to be outer and ```for ii in range``` - the inner loop.

Comment: You just need your `jj` to range over `range(ii, filename_list.__len()__)`. Probably some off-by-1 errors in there but they should be trivial to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're also changing `jj` in your inner loop's iteration. Try this:

```
jj = 0

for ii in range(filename_list.__len__()):
    for jj in range(ii+1, filename_list.__len__()):
        print(str(ii) + " " + str(jj) + "\n")

    print("=" * 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

while `J+=1` does increment j, the new value is ignored, as in the next line you're telling Python to start j at zero (`range(x)` is a range starting at x and ending at x-1)

How about:

```
for ii in range(filename_list.__len__()):
    for jj in range(ii + 1, filename_list.__len__()):
        if ii != jj:
            print(str(ii) + " " + str(jj) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the starting point in the second range like below:

```
jj = 0
n=3

for ii in range(n):
    jj += 1
    for jj in range(ii,n):
        if ii != jj:
            print(str(ii) + " " + str(jj) + "\n")

    print("=" * 5)
```

I change the `filename_list.__len__()` into `n`

you can see I add the ii in the second range that means start the jj from ii, not from zero

Answer (score 0):

the inner for loop you could start from ii, since ii it is incremented with 1 after each loop of the inner for:

```
for ii in range(filename_list.__len__()):
    for jj in range(ii, filename_list.__len__()):
        if ii != jj:
            print(str(ii) + " " + str(jj) + "\n")

    print("=" * 5)
```

output:

```
0 1

0 2

=====
1 2
```